# Multiple where in mysql query not returning anything

Tags: mysql

I know that this is a very easy question, but why isn't my query returning anything ?

```
mysql> select * from notifications;
+----+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | sec_user_id | item_id | action | date                |
+----+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |        NULL |    NULL |   NULL | 2015-10-09 23:47:36 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from notifications where user_id = 1 and action = NULL;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `action = null` to `action is null`.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` cannot be equal to anything, including itself. You should use `is` with it..

```
select id from notifications where user_id = 1 and action is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `IS NULL`:

```
select id 
from notifications 
where user_id = 1 
and action IS NULL
```